# отправка чисел в com-порт python

Tags: python, arduino, serial

В программировании новичок.
Пишу скрипт для управления сервоприводами ардуино в питоне. Суть скрипта следующая: в цикле последовательно вычисляются значения угла поворота сервопривода. Эти значения мне нужно отправить через ком-порт на ардуинку. Почему-то скрипт не работает. При этом непосредственно в ардуино данная последовательность чисел через ком-порт дает необходимый результат.
Скрипт:

```
import serial
import time
import math

arduino=serial.Serial('COM3', 9600)
time.sleep(0.5)
x = -1
while x < 1:
    y = x * x - 5 #это функция, график которой буду строить
    phi = math.acos(0.05*math.sqrt((x+10)*(x+10)+y*y)) #здесь и дальше вычисления
    alfa = math.atan(y/(x+10))
    psi = alfa + 2.09 - phi
    deg_psi = psi * 180 / 3.14
    x=x+0.1
    deg_psi = int (deg_psi) #здесь посчитано конечное значение угла
    arduino.write(b'deg_psi') #пытаюсь передать это значение в сериал порт
```

На всякий случай еще код ардуино:

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo servo_1;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.setTimeout(50);
  servo_1.attach(9);
  servo_1.write(0);
  }
void loop() {
  while (Serial.available()>0) {
    int val_1 = Serial.parseInt();
    servo_1.write(val_1);
    delay(100);
  }
}
```

Пробовал в строке `arduino.write(b'deg_psi')` менять на `arduino.write([deg_psi])` но тоже без результатов.

Comment: Уберите у ардуино Serial.setTimeout(50); иначе у Вас из while (Serial.available()>0) выходит через 50 млсек.  А на питоне arduino.write(byte(f'{deg_psi}') ) - как-то так передавать надо

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то строка `arduino.write(b'deg_psi')` отправляет в порт текст «deg_psi», а не значение переменной. Соответственно на принимающей стороне `Serial.parseInt()` всегда возвращает 0, потому что не видит числа в буфере.

Вам нужно взять значение deg_psi, преобразовать его в последовательность цифр, и коды символов, соответствующих этим цифрам, отправить в порт.

Проще всего это сделать преобразовав число в троку средствами питона: `str(deg_psi)`. Но так как `write` принимает последовательность байт, а не символов, нужно преобразовать указав кодировку, то есть используя метод `encode`. Нас устроит и кодировка по умолчанию.

Итого последняя строка в цикле должна выглядеть так: `arduino.write(str(deg_psi).encode())`

Answer (score 1):

Python:

```
import serial
import time
import math

arduino=serial.Serial('COM3', 9600)
time.sleep(0.5)
x = -1
while x < 1:
    ...
    deg_psi = int (deg_psi)
    # Возможно здесь надо ещё передавать "\n",
    # чтобы parseInt на стороне ардуино знал, где закончится число
    # Здесь передаются байты например deg_psi = 123
    # передаётся (HEX) 0x31 0x32 0x33 0x0D
    arduino.write(bytes(f"{deg_psi}\n")
```

Arduino:

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo servo_1;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.setTimeout(50);
  servo_1.attach(9);
  servo_1.write(0);
  }

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available()>0) {        
    int val_1 = Serial.parseInt();
    servo_1.write(val_1);
    delay(250)
  }
}
```

Здесь в loop() наверное правильно будет использовать Serial.readStringUntil("\n"); чтобы быть точно уверенным, что все цифры числа пришли, а не половина.
например:
65 < Timeout > 34\n -> 6534\n

Накапливать данные и когда пришло
"\n" - уже обрабатывать полученные данные,
преобразовать строку в число